# Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service API-GATEWAY

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api-gateway

I am working on 3 spring boot application from which 2 applications i am using for communication between the two i am using feign client also i am 1 application for  api-gateway which has all the entries for diffrent application
feign client controller is

```
@Autowired
    PaymentService paymentService;
    @PostMapping(value = "/payments/{appointmentId}")
    public String changePaymentStatus(@PathVariable(name = "appointmentId")String appointmentId){
        paymentService.changePaymentStatus(appointmentId);
        return "Done";
    }
```

here is the feign client code

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@FeignClient(name = "API-GATEWAY")
public interface AppointmentServiceClient {
    @RequestMapping(value = "${appointmentApp.changePaymentStatus}",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String changePaymentStatus(@PathVariable(name = "appointmentId")String appointmentId);
}
```

Here i have used "API-GATEWAY" because the there is one application running with this name and its application.yml file is here

```
  port: 9191

spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: DOCTOR-SERVICE
          uri: lb://DOCTOR-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/doctor_app/**

        - id: APPOINTMENT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://APPOINTMENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/appointment_app/**

        - id: USER-ON-BOARDING-SERVICE
          uri: lb://USER-ON-BOARDING-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/user_app/**

        - id: RATING-SERVICE
          uri: lb://RATING-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/rating_app/**

        - id: PAYMENT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://PAYMENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/payment_app/**
    discovery:
      enabled: true
```

Also the value in @RequestMapping of AppointmentServiceClient has application.properties as shown here

```
appointmentApp.address = http://APPOINTMENT-SERVICE 
appointmentApp.changePaymentStatus = /appointment_app/v1/payments/{appointmentId}
```

Here i am want to call APPOINTMENT-SERVICE through api-gateway using feign client

Also the controller method which the feign client is trying to call is

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/payments/{appointmentId}")
    public String changePaymentStatus(@PathVariable(name = "appointmentId")String appointmentId){
        appointmentService.changePaymentStatus(appointmentId);
        return "done";
    }
```

By doing a POST from postman i am getting feign.FeignException$ServiceUnavailable: [503] during [POST] to [http://API-GATEWAY/appointment_app/v1/payments/ndjkccbc7868] [AppointmentServiceClient#changePaymentStatus(String)]: [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service API-GATEWAY]

Comment: PostMapping(value = "/payments/{appointmentId}") is used as client by user and @PostMapping(value = "/v1/payments/{appointmentId}") is used by feign client both are different

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/41401009/2886891, or https://stackoverflow.com/a/68351653/2886891 help?